# Internal server error virtual products WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, memberpress

we are having issues only with virtual products during the checkout in WooCommerce. The site use virtual products to sell memberships with Memberpress plugin + Memberpress woocommerce add on.
It has install WordPress: 5.5.1, Memberpress Plus 1.8.11 and Memberpress WooCommerce 1.0.5 + Salient Theme

URL: https://growclubdevoto.com/

[Capture of the Internal server error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YiHqy.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply you can add this below code to your config.php file before `/* That's all, stop editing! Happy publishing. */`

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
```

Comment: Yes after asking i did add those lines and check the error logs. It was a shipping plugin that was making the error. Thanks!

Comment: @BrandVan you are most welcome